# Transfer of BTC the wallet address p2pkh to wallet address p2sh

Tags: wallet, address

Is it possible to send BTC from wallet having address type p2pkh to the receiver wallet address p2psh

Answer (score 2):

As long as a utxo is spendable, there are no restrictions on the types of outputs - any kind of input can be used to create any kind of (valid) output, which will usually be one of the well known ones - i.e. p2pkh, p2sh, p2wpkh, p2wsh, op_return, p2ms, p2pk.